# How do I load arbitrary data from a url PHP?

Tags: php, url, scripting, load

This question is simple. What function would I use in a PHP script to load data from a URL into a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CURL is usually a good solution: http://www.php.net/curl

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$html = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: What should i do if i want to get an element say with html `id="simple_id"` ?

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for

```
$url_data = file_get_contents("http://example.com/examplefile.txt");
```

Comment: OK, it works. But not for wikipedia.org.

For example:
` file_get_contents("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/apple");`
fails
This is a problem because this is the site that I am trying to load data from"

Answer (score 2):

With file wrappers you can use file_get_contents to access http resources (pretty much just GET requests, no POST).  For more complicated http requests you can use the curl wrappers if you have them installed.  Check php.net for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Snoopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/), a PHP class that simulates a web browser:

```
include "Snoopy.class.php";
$snoopy = new Snoopy;
$snoopy->fetchtext("http://www.example.com");
$html = $snoopy->results;
```